# Use OpenLdap to summarize multiple ActiveDirectory - ldapadd append objects to new base dn

Tags: ldap, synchronization, openldap

I've to create a big directory where all users from multiple active directorys are referenced. I just need some few Informations like original DN and Name , maybe mail...

I decided to build my trees like follows:

```
[collector directory]
|
|-->[ OU <Name of Location1> ] -> [ {Objects Location1} ]
|
|-->[ OU <Name of Location2> ] -> [ {Objects Location2} ]
```

I started by installing openldap on a debian system and created ldap export with ldapserch from  and stored it in an .ldsi file.

I read man ldapadd but i coudn't find a parameter to append a root dn, so i created a bash script and just search and replaced the part of the dn:

```
Original [DC=example1,DC=org] => [OU=example1,OU=org,OU=location1,DC=collector,DC=com]
```

sadly this won't work because all entrys that contains special chars (ä,ü,ö..) are encoded to base64, i tryed to do some "base64decoding replacing and encoding and replacing again" but this workarround just feels bad to me and i dont get a working result...

I searched a while and i found just LSC but it seems oversized and i've to use java and java sql.. witch i like to avoid....

is there a simple solution? do i've to use lsc or have to script this search and replace thing?

Comment: You should be looking into the OpenLDAP 'translucent' overlay or the LDAP backend, rather than building an entire new DIT.

Comment: thank you, that seems to be the solution.
but I've no idea how to configure that.
I'm not able to find a config example or description in the openldap documentation with keyword overlay / translucent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking into either:

1. the OpenLDAP [`translucent`](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-translucent&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.3-Release&format=html) overlay, or
2. the [LDAP backend](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#LDAP),

rather than building an entire new DIT.

See also the Zytrax [OpenLDAP for Rocket Scientists](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/) guide, which is pretty complete and reliable.