# Search against multiple databases with OpenLdap

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to combine my test openldap (MDB database) with my production AD installation, so I can have the production users access my test systems. In order to do that I've created two databases in my slapd.conf, as follows:

```
#######################################################################
# database definitions
#######################################################################
include /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd-meta-ad-prd.conf
include /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd-mdb.conf
```

The configuration file for the AD connection is as follows:

```
database    meta
suffix         "dc=bsi,dc=test,dc=com"
uri             "ldap://miadc01.mia.usa/dc=bsi,dc=test,dc=com"
suffixmassage   "dc=bsi,dc=test,dc=com" "dc=mia,dc=usa"
idassert-bind bindmethod=simple binddn="cn=Test User,cn=users,dc=mia,dc=usa" credentials=xxxxx
```

The configurtion file for the MDB is:

```
database        mdb
maxsize         1073741824

suffix          "dc=test,dc=com"
rootdn          "cn=Manager,dc=test,dc=com"
```

So the first database (meta AD) uses the sufix "**dc=bsi,dc=test,dc=com**", and the second one (mdb) uses "**dc=test,dc=com**". The idea is that the AD would appear as a branch of the development database. I've found that I can search the AD by using the search DN "**dc=bsi,dc=test,dc=com**", but if I try to search with DN "**dc=test,dc=com**", only the test database is searched. The search does not combine both databases. How can I do it?

EDIT

Note that I can search in the AD branch if I using the search DN "**dc=bsi,dc=test,dc=com**", so the connection to the AD is working fine. The problem is that the search with DN "**dc=test,dc=com**" is not searching in both databases.

Comment: Duplicate of [Use OpenLdap to summarize multiple ActiveDirectory - ldapadd append objects to new base dn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483947/use-openldap-to-summarize-multiple-activedirectory-ldapadd-append-objects-to-n)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I'm asking why the setup I have is not searching in all databases, which is not answered in the question you put the link to.